# C++: find in set of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, constants

My problem is illustrated by following example:

```
#include <set>

class A {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A * p = &a;
    const A * cp = &a;

    std::set<A*> s;
    s.insert(p);
    s.find(cp);
}
```

Compilation ends in:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:13:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘const A*’ to ‘std::set<A*>::key_type {aka A*}’ [-fpermissive]
         s.find(cp);
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/set:61:0,
                 from a.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_set.h:701:7: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = A*; _Compare = std::less<A*>; _Alloc = std::allocator<A*>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<A*>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = A*]’
       find(const key_type& __x)
```

I know why it does not compile, but is there any solution less ugly and brutal than `s.find((A*)cp)`? Both set and const pointer are given.

Comment: Is changing the set's type to `set<const A*>` an option?

Comment: `but is there any solution less ugly and brutal`  Don't have a set of pointers.

Comment: `const A *` isn't the same as `A *`!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie A set of smart pointers wouldn't fare any better.

Comment: In `find`, you are searching for a `const` element, however the set is declared as having non-const elements.

Comment: Not sure what the intent of `cp` is supposed to be.  You sure you don't want a `A * const cp`?  That works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An option is to use C++14 [transparent operator functors](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm) together with [heterogeneous lookup](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm):

```
std::set<A*, std::less<>> s;
s.find(cp);
```

Unfortunately, heterogeneous lookup is not currently supported in libstdc++, but [it's marked as WIP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014). (It's available in clang/libc++ and [will be available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/06/c-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) in the next version of Visual Studio.) Without it, you are pretty much stuck with `const_cast`'ing `cp`.

Comment: Meh, you've been half a minute faster. I went through the github draft and used blame to find those document numbers..

Comment: @dyp I cheated and used the libstdc++ status page :)

Comment: Well I can at least paste my live example here (and delete my comment from the OP). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ab721111ad74620 ("I have only proved that it compiles, not tried it")

Comment: The Boost multi-index container has had heterogeneous lookup for a long time.  I've wished Boost.Container had more of that, but didn't at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Tragically, `set`'s querying methods aren't templated on the key type (they really should be), so `lower_bound`, `equal_range`, etc. won't help.

Your only options, assuming that the variable types aren't negotiable, are to cast away the pointer's constness, or `reinterpret_cast` the set to a `set<const A*>`. The latter in some ways feels nicer to me, but it's technically unsafe.

Cast away the constness. Use `const_cast` to do it, to make it clear that that's the only thing the cast is doing. If you like, wrap that and the find in a free function; if a piece of code is being evil, it's a good idea to make the evil thing the *only* thing it does.

Comment: *"Tragically, set's querying methods aren't templated on the key type (they really should be)"* This has up- and downsides. I remember a bug that was caused by such heterogeneous lookup member functions combined with homogeneous comparison functions (which caused a conversion for every comparison). See T.C.'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use find with a const_cast:

```
s.find(const_cast<A*>(cp));
```